# PIL ImageTk AttributeError, can't display ImageTk on window

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've been working on a small program to convert PNG, JPG and JPEG files to .ICO files. This was relatively simple to do, but while I was trying to display the selected PNG image in Tkinter using PIL's ImageTk, I get a strange error.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import re
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
pathToImage = ''
selectedImage = ''
def make_square(im, min_size=256, fill_color = (0, 0, 0)):    # Puts the selected image into a black square
    x, y = im.size
    size = max(min_size, x, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (size,size), fill_color)
    new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
    return new_im

def select_image(): # Function that is run when Select PNG button is clicked
    global pathToImage
    pathToImage = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('PNG Files','*.png'),('JPG Files','*.jpg'),('JPEG Files','*.jpeg')]) # Gets path to PNG, JPG or JPEG image
    image = Image.open(pathToImage) # Opens image in PIL
    image = make_square(im=image) # Turns image into square for ICO conversion
    #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR Among these 3 lines
    global selectedImage # Here I try to tell Python I'm referring to the global variable selectedImage
    selectedImage = (ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pathToImage)) # selectedImage is given the value of ImageTk.PhotoImage with the source image being the path of the selected image
    Label(root, image=selectedImage).pack() # Throws an error for some reason
    # Rest of the code works fine
    image.save('output.ico')
    Label(root,text='Converted file stored in the same folder as \'PNG to ICO.py\'').pack()


Button(root,text='Select PNG', command=select_image).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried saving the image to display to a variable, but that doesn't seem to work either. Could anyone help point out what I did wrong? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What's the error?It show me `KeyError: the path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code.

- In your line `(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pathToImage))` **you are passing a path (`str`) which is not what it should take, `ImageTk.PhotoImage` takes instance of `Image(path)`**. So change it to the image getting returned by `make_square` function.
- Every time when the button is clicked, it'll create a new `label` if that's what you want then ignore this, if not then **create your labels outside of the function `select_image` after you create the `Button` and later in the function update them.**
- I don't really get why you are using `global` when you can achieve your purpose without making variables `pathToImage`  or `selectedImage` unless you want to access that image later in the program.

---

*Here is the improved version of your code.*

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import re
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def make_square(im, min_size=256, fill_color = (0, 0, 0)):    # Puts the selected image into a black square
    x, y = im.size
    size = max(min_size, x, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (size,size), fill_color)
    new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
    return new_im

def select_image(): # Function that is run when Select PNG button is clicked
    pathToImage = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('PNG Files','*.png'),('JPG Files','*.jpg'),('JPEG Files','*.jpeg')])
    image = Image.open(str(pathToImage)) # Opens image in PIL
    image = make_square(im=image) # Turns image into square for ICO conversion
    selectedImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
    imglabel.img = selectedImage  # create a reference of the image
    imglabel['image'] = selectedImage
    # selectedImage is given the value of ImageTk.PhotoImage with the source image being the path of the selected image
    # Rest of the code works fine
    image.save('output.ico', 'ICO')
    infolabel['text'] = 'Converted file stored in the same folder as \'PNG to ICO.py\''

root = Tk()

but1 = Button(root,text='Select PNG', command=select_image)
but1.pack()

imglabel = Label(root)
imglabel.pack()

infolabel = Label(root)
infolabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```